# Python - Multiple Criteria Condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to Python and need some guidance in Dataframe.
There are two columns `Product` and `sub-product` What I am trying to achieve is for a specific product(s), what are the sub-products under that product(s).

Only know how to display the distinct count of Product and sub-product

```
complaints['Product'].unique()
complaints['sub-Product'].unique()
```

Please help

Comment: please put your sample data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like these

```
product_name = 'Some Product name'
complaints[complaints['Product'] == product_name]['sub-Product'].unique()
```